# How to go from one view to another in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am still learning and not sure how to do this, I have in  my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Detail(int userId)
{
  var user = ZincService.GetUserForId(userId);
  UserDetailViewModel userDetail = new UserDetailViewModel();
  userDetail.UserId = userId;
  userDetail.Email = user.Email;
  userDetail.Firstname = user.Firstname;
  userDetail.Surname = user.Surname;
  return View(userDetail);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeEmailAddress()
{
  return View();
}
```

In my Detail view:

```
  <div class="section _100">
     <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)%> 
         <div>
             <%: Model.Email  %>
             <%: Model.UserId %>
         </div>
         <div>                                      
             <%: Html.ActionLink("Change Email Address",  "ChangeEmailAddress", "User", new { area = "Admin", @id = Model.UserId, @email = Model.Email, @name = Model.Firstname }, 0) %>  

             <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)%>    
         </div>
  </div>
```

I just want to go from here in the view to another view(ChangeEmailAddress) where the user can actually change his email from old to new?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put 0 as last argument of the ActionLink? It should be null.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Change Email Address",  
    "ChangeEmailAddress", 
    "User", 
    new { 
        area = "Admin", 
        id = Model.UserId, 
        email = Model.Email, 
        name = Model.Firstname 
    }, 
    null
) %>
```

Now your `ChangeEmailAddress` action could take the model as parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeEmailAddress(UserDetailViewModel user)
{
    return View(user);
}
```

Then you should define the corresponding `ChangeEmailAddress.aspx` view which will be rendered by this controller action and strongly typed to your view model.

But a better approach is to send only the user id in the request and then retrieve the actual user object using this id:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Change Email Address",  
    "ChangeEmailAddress", 
    "User", 
    new { 
        area = "Admin", 
        id = Model.UserId, 
    }, 
    null
) %>
```

and then:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeEmailAddress(int id)
{
    // retrieve the user object using the id
    ...
}
```